# Group structures on the cartesian product of two groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

This question probably has a simple and immediate answer which escapes me now. (And, I should admit, it's more my curiosity than anything else.) The only natural way to construct a group structure on the cartesian product $G\times H$ of two groups $G$ and $H$ (in particular, ``natural'' to me means that on each factor the group product should be the original one) is the semi-direct product in the case when one group acts on another one by automorphisms. Are there any natural constructions of a group structure on $G\times H$  where neither factor is a normal subgroup?

Update: I was pointed out that the notion of Zappa-Szep product that appears in the answer given by Steven Gubkin  is also mentioned in [an earlier MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5528/when-does-a-subgroup-h-of-a-group-g-have-a-complement-in-g); I thought I'd link it here for some sort of connectivity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia to the rescue!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa-Szep_product

Comment: Dear Steven, thanks! That (more precisely, the part on external Zappa-Szep products) is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Interstingly enough, this construction -- which I knew but not by name -- is intimately related to the subject of "dressing transformations" in integrable systems.  The actions of H on K and of K on H are abstract analogues of the dressing actions in Poisson-Lie groups.

Comment: @Jose: Yes, and also there is an analogous version for Hopf algebras.  Indeed, the "Drinfeld Double" of a Hopf algebra is a special example.

Comment: As José and Theo remarked, this is certainly an interesting notion, but I don't see any general (non-tautological) $\textit{construction}.$

Comment: @Victor: I was inclined to say the same after I first read this, but then I looked again into the part on external Zappa-Szep products, and I should admit that in a sense this is a construction in the same way the semi-direct product is a construction. The semi-direct product depends on some data (action of H on K); similarly, this product depends on the mappings $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfying compatibility condition...

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko: The relationship with semi-direct product is closer than your last remark hints at: $\alpha$ must be a left action of $K$ on $H$, and $\beta$ must be a right action of $H$ on $K$. (And then those two actions must satisfy some compatibility assumption.) And indeed, if either of these actions is trivial, then one recovers the semi-direct product.