# When does a normal subgroup H of a group G have a complement in G?

Tags: gr.group-theory

When does all normal subgroups of a group have complement? This question is different from question [When does a subgroup H of a group G have a complement in G?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/5528/56173)

Related to this question I ask is following https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824173/complement-of-normal-subgroups-and-free-groups

Comment: When $G$ is simple for example. I think the question is too broad.

Comment: If $G$ is a semi-direct product of $H$ and $G/H$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Classifying_split_extensions

Comment: although I had asked for some kind of classification or well known theorems like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-Zassenhaus_theorem. But I just want clarification on your comment. If G isomorphic to semidirect product of H and G/H, Isomorphic image of {e}*G/H will be required subspace, right?

Comment: By the way, the question in the title is different from the question in the first sentence of the body; Ian Agol is answering the question in the title.